# Apache Spark convert from join result set (K, (V, W)) to (V,W) key value pair

Tags: python, apache-spark

I do have result set from join in Apache Spark in (K, (V, W)) format. I need to reduce it to (V,W) using Apache Spark in Python. What function should I use to convert (K,(V,W)) to (V,W)?

I am new to Apache Spark and reviewed functions available for Apache Spark. But I don't find that suits this case.

Comment: provide sample data always when you need an answer. I am curious if you have tried using map(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to the `map` solution proposed by @Pangea, you can also use the `values` method:

```
animals=sc.parallelize([(1,"mouse"),(2,"elephant"),(3,"cat")])
fruits=sc.parallelize([(1,"apple"),(1,"orange"),(3,"banana")])
fruitAnimals=animals.join(fruits).values()
fruitAnimals.collect()
#[('mouse', 'apple'), ('mouse', 'orange'), ('cat', 'banana')]
```